# add new element if image does not exist

Tags: jquery

I am trying to look for an image with class `pic` and if it does not exists i would like to perferm some task and if it does exist i dont want to do anything. I have tried the following code with no success. i get the alert no matter what i do .

**img code**

```
<img src="" class="pic">
```

**jquery**

```
$(".stxt, .stxt2").each(function() {
if ($(this).find("img.pic").length === 0) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var unitSize = 10; // width (and height) of one square
            var unitsWide = 6; // number of squares along x-axis
            var unitsTall = 6; // number of squares along y-axis
            var drawing = $('<div class="drawing"></div>').css({
                width: unitSize * unitsWide
            });
            for (var i = 0; i < unitsWide * unitsTall; i++) {
                var randomColor;
                randomColor = Math.random() * 0x1000000; // 0 < randomColor < 0x1000000
                randomColor = Math.floor(randomColor); // 0 < randomColor <= 0xFF5F0FF
                randomColor = randomColor.toString(16); // hex representation randomColor
                randomColor = ("000000" + randomColor).slice(-6); // leading zeros added
                randomColor = "#" + randomColor; // # added
                $('<span class="square"></span>').css({
                    display: 'block',
                    float: 'left',
                    width: unitSize,
                    height: unitSize,
                    'background-color': randomColor
                }).appendTo(drawing);
            }
            drawing.insertBefore($(this).find("div.dtxt2, div.dtxt"));
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Where are you calling this from? What is `this` in this?

Comment: I don't think you want to put $(document).ready() inside of the each().  It looks like if you can't find a picture, you are putting a 60x60 multicolored block in its place?  Some HTML may be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

```
jQuery(function(){
    if ($("img.pic").length === 0) { 

      alert("Doing something");

    }else{

      //Do nothing

    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle that using `onerror` event of the `img` tag

HTML

```
<img src="" class="pic" onerror="HandleError(this)">
```

JavaScript

```
function HandleError(obj_img){
    alert("Doing Something");
    //obj_img.src = 'path/to/image-not-found/image';
}
```

Or use jQuery like this.

```
$('img.pic').error(function() {
    alert("Doing Something");
    //$(this).attr("src", "path/to/image-not-found/image");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what "this" is in the context, but you could instead try

```
if ($("img.pic").length === 0) { 
    //Code
}
```